# How to safely upgrade the version of libxml2 on our server

Tags: linux, python, plone, zope

We currently libxml2 2.7.7 installed on our servers.  This is a dependency of lxml which we use on two difference clusters of Zope instances runing our 2 Plone CMS applications.

We'd like to upgrade to libxml2 2.7.8 but I'm unclear of what steps you'd take to achieve this safely, without causing problems to users of each CMS.

I understand how to unpack, configure, make and make install the package.  It's what else needs doing that I'm unclear on.

Some specific questions:

- how does this impact the unpacked lxml egg with its *.pyc, *.pyo files already generated? For example, do I need to delete those files to pick up the change?
- can you  perform the upgrade whilst the CMSs are still running? If yes, do you need to restart afterwards to pick up the change?